# Android ImageButton resize in small screen size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, imagebutton

I have this `ImageButton` in my android application:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sleep_timer_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/sleep_btn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline31"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline24"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline23"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30" />
```

The problem is that in 5.0" screen its look ok:

[image]

But when I check it on 2.7" screen this is what I get:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: ad where you put your image ? (which folder) also what kind of drawable it is?

Comment: You include a version of your bitmap designed for smaller screens. Read the [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: put appropriate size images in drawable folder of different resolution like hdpi, xhdpi etc. Or put largest size image in drawable folder and remove image from all other resolution folders like hdpi,xhdpi etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change ImageButton  scale type as

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```